# Не робот на 18%

Tags: поддержка, знаки

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/196/not-a-robot

В описании знака говорится

> Встретил сотрудника Stack Overflow на [событии, организованном Stack Overflow или при её участии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events), в котором участвовало 50 человек и более.
>   Знак можно получать многократно.

Однако знаков вручено 9, а не 50. Возможно, описание надо поменять?

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Ну противоречия как бы нет все равно, может остальные не имеют акков на SO или не хотят получать знак или ...